# Accessing a dynamitcally added buttoncolumn's (in a Datagrid) click event. C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I dynamically create a Datagrid and add in a new buttoncolumn how do I access the buttoncolumn_click event?

Thanks.

Comment: there is a typo on the title:dynamitcally-> dynamically

Comment: Do you need to actually access that individual button's Click event, or simply perform an action whenever a button in that column is clicked?

Comment: No I just need to perform an action whenever a button in that column is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

  dg.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

  dg.Columns.Add(new ButtonColumn {
    CommandName = "add",
    HeaderText = "Event Details",
    Text = "Details",
    ButtonType = ButtonColumnType.PushButton
  });

  dg.DataSource = getDataTable();
  dg.DataBind();

  dg.ItemCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(dg_ItemCommand);

  pnlMain.Controls.Add(dg);
}

protected void dg_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "add")
  {
    throw new Exception("add it!");
  }
}

protected DataTable getDataTable()
{
  // returns your data table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article on the MSDN site clearly explains how to go about [adding a button into a datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984252(VS.71).aspx). Instead of using the click event of the button you'll use the command event of the DataGrid. Each button will be passing specific commandarguments that you will set.

This article shows [how to use the command event with buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx). In it you use CommandArguments and CommandNames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I create the datagrid:

System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid Datagridtest = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();

```
        Datagridtest.Width = 600;
        Datagridtest.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
        Datagridtest.CellPadding = 1;

        ButtonColumn bc = new ButtonColumn();
        bc.CommandName = "add";
        bc.HeaderText = "Event Details";
        bc.Text = "Details";
        bc.ButtonType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonColumnType.PushButton;
        Datagridtest.Columns.Add(bc);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Datagridtest);

        Datagridtest.DataSource = dt;
        Datagridtest.DataBind();
```

And here is the event I am trying to use:

protected void Datagridtest_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ....
    }

Thought that might help because I can't seem to capture the event at all.